# Problema al pasar parametros del controlador al modelo Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Buenas noches, estoy haciendo una pagina web con el framework Ruby on Rails 5.1, para aprender mas sobre le manejo del mismo.

Bueno, resulta que estoy haciendo un método para que un usuario pueda seguir a otro usuario, lo estoy haciendo con CoffeScript, donde utilizo un botón para generar la acción, creo un archivo JSON donde le paso de parámetro el ID (friend_id) del usuario al cual quiero seguir, luego desde el controlador del usuario recibo ese archivo JSON y lo filtro con un método post_params de la siguiente manera.

app.js.coffe:

```
$ = jQuery

$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $('#follow_btn').on "click", ->
      friend = $(this).data("friend")
      boton = $(this)
      $.ajax "/usuario/follow", 
      type: "POST"
      dataType: "JSON"
      data: {usuario: { friend_id: friend }}
      success: (data)->
        console.log data
        boton.slideUp()
        alert friend
      error: (err)->
        console.log err
        alert "No hemos podido crear la amistad"
```

Controlador del Usuario:

```
class UsuarioController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def show
     @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
  end

  def follow
    respond_to do |format|
        if current_usuario.follow!(post_params)
            format.json {head :no_content}
        else
            format.json {render json: "Se encontraron errores"}
        end
     end
  end

  private
  def post_params
     params.require(:usuario).permit(:friend_id)
  end
end
```

entonces aquí viene el problema, cuando se ejecuta esta linea **current_usuario.follow!(post_params)**

hace que se ejecute el metodo follow! del modelo usuario

```
def follow!(amigo_id)
  friendships.create(friend_id = amigo_id)
end
```

luego de esto, se genera el error, si esta guardando el registro, pero el id del usuario al que sigo (es decir el friend_id) lo guarda como nil, quiere decir que no esta llegando la información del controlador al modelo.

intente pasar directamente el ID desde el controlador de esta manera

```
current_usuario.follow!(3)
```

de esta manera si esta guardando el registro de manera apropiada.

asi tengo el modelo usuario.

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook, :twitter]

  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships

  has_many :follows, through: :friendships, source: :friend

  has_many :followers_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", 
  foreign_key: "friend_id"

  has_many :followers, through: :followers_friendships, source: 
  :usuario

  def follow!(amigo_id)
    friendships.create!(friend_id: amigo_id)
  end

  def can_follow?(amigo_id)
    not amigo_id == self.id or friendships.where(friend_id: 
    amigo_id).size > 0
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, 
  length: {in:5..20, too_short: "Al menos 5 caracteres", too_long: 
  "Maximo 20 caracteres"}

  def self.find_or_create_by_omniauth(auth)
    usuario = self.find_or_create_by(provider: auth[:provider], uid: 
    auth[:uid]) do |user|
        user.nombre = auth[:name]
        user.apellido = auth[:last_name]
        user.username = auth[:username]
        user.email = auth[:email]
        user.uid = auth[:uid]
        user.provider = auth[:provider]
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

No se por que no llega la informacion al modelo mediante los parametros, ya he verificado que el json le envie la informacion al controlador y si lo hace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás pasando `post_params` como parámetro:

```
current_usuario.follow!(post_params)
```

lo cual es incorrecto, porque eso te retorna un hash con los parámetros permitidos por tu controlador, que al final tiene una estructura del tipo `{usuario: { friend_id: 1 }}`.
Lo correcto sería que uses:

```
current_usuario.follow!(post_params[:usuario][:friend_id])
```